# How to display the stars according to the ratings in html view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building an asp.net mvc application. I display the ratings of a resource on a page using stars. Depending on the average rating the equivalent number of stars should be displayed.

I have written out the following code:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> // displays 1 star
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span> // display 1 empty star

// Displays the average ratings float value
@foreach(var resource in ViewBag.Resources)
{
  <p>@resource.Ratings</p>
}
```

I want something like this to be displayed

```
@foreach(var resource in ViewBag.Resources)
{
  @resource.Ratings * <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" /> (1-@resource.Ratings) * <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" />
}
```

How can this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(@resource.Ratings); i++)
{ 
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
}
@for (int i = Int32.Parse(@resource.Ratings); i < 5; i++ )
{ 
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
}
@resource.Ratings stars
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. But what if you have a rating of say 3.5, how would you handle that?

Comment: @JohnieNdoshSpax did you find anything if we need to show 3.5 stars?

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript Library for displaying stars in efficient way and good UI, you have many options 
[Five stars rating](http://callmenick.com/post/five-star-rating-component-with-javascript-css)
[bootstrap-star-rating](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating)

Comment: Thanks for help. I got a simple way of doing it.

Comment: Share it with us or mark it as solved, to help other looking for same thing

Comment: Yes, I posted it as an answer.